# Anyway to check for container height and change CSS accordingly?

Tags: jquery, html, css

Lets say, for example, I have a container that takes up 100% of the page and then at the bottom (as part of that container) a footer. The footer is positioned on left:0px and bottom:0px.

Is there a way, using JQuery for example, to check the height of that container, and if it is below a certain amount, remove the css on the footer that positions it at 0px 0px?

Sample html:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="footer">
    </div>
</div>
```

Sample css:

```
.container { width:100%; }
.footer { height:42px; position:absolute; bottom:3px; left:0px; width:100%; }
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit more clearly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using jQuery as follows:

```
var $containerHeight = $('.container').height();
if(height < yourMagicNumberHere) {
  $('.footer').css({
    position: 'static',
    bottom: 'auto',
    left: 'auto'
  });
}
```

Comment: No need to assume, It is tagged :) (+1)

Comment: Is there any way to get this to do it on (document).ready and also when they resize the window?

Answer (score 0):

Is that really necessary though? Is there something wrong with the following?

```
.container { }
.footer { height:42px; margin-bottom: 3px; }
```

The footer is still gonna be at the bottom/end of the container.

Comment: but the footer will not be at the bottom of the window?

Comment: Ahh, I see. I though it was supposed to be attached to the end of the container. My bad :)